# 'enhancing over' vs 'enhancing than'

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about how to phrase something:

> "enhances the performance over the conventional structure"

or

> "enhances the performance than the conventional structure"?

Would any native speaker be so kind to tell which is right? Thanks

Comment: This question really needs more context.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the rest of the sentence, it is not possible to provide a definitive answer, but most likely:

- "than" is wrong;
- "over" would be better;
- but I would write "compared with":

> enhances the performance *compared with* the conventional structure

Comment: I wouldn't say "compared with" is wrong, but I definitely think "compared to" is more common and idiomatic. (Maybe this is a UK/US thing, I'm not sure.)

Comment: It maybe partly UK/US, but I think it may also depend on the first (missing) part of the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

"performs better than the conventional structure" is much clearer, if that is what you mean to say.

Comment: Expand on the answer to make it better.

Comment: To expand on Mist's comment: You have answered the "what" of the question. However, answers on Stack Exchange should contain the "why" as well. Without knowing why an answer is correct, future visitors to the site may not be able to apply existing answers to their own questions. Additional information you can add will help these visitors from the future and possibly save them the time of having to ask a new question.